# Where should I ask about computational fluid dynamics?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have questions about [computational fluid dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_fluid_dynamics)(CFD) and fluid simulation related subjects. Where should I ask these questions?

Assume I'm working on CFD software development, testing and fluid simulation related works such as turbine design.

Questions may based on physics, mathematics and coding also.

Example question:

> What is the difference between *K epsiolon* and *SST* model?

Comment: Please note that your example question serves as a question title at best. You'll certainly need to add details about your current knowledge, what you've been already researching (including the site itself), and where your confusion (lack of understanding) actually lies. Every site has a section in their [help] titled _How do I ask a good question_, that you can use as a checklist to add good contributions to the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) is what you're looking for.  From the site:

> Computational Science Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for scientists using computers to solve scientific problems.

They have a [fluid-dynamics](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluid-dynamics) tag there.